# python django logging timerotatingfilehandler

Tags: python, django, logging

I use the `logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler` to rotate the access log in my django project. The setting of 'when' attribute is 'midnight', and the rotate works well most of the time, but sometimes it does not work as I want to, just like below:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 5.5M Jun 28 23:59 sd.log.2014-06-28
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 5.1M Jun 27 23:59 sd.log.2014-06-27
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 5.2M Jun 26 23:59 sd.log.2014-06-26
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  146 Jun 26 00:00 sd.log.2014-06-25
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 5.1M Jun 24 23:59 sd.log.2014-06-24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work  123 Jun 24 00:00 sd.log.2014-06-23
-rw-rw-r-- 1 work work 5.2M Jun 22 23:59 sd.log.2014-06-22
```

Both the log of the `2014-06-23` and `2014-06-25` are rotated at `00:00` while others at `23:59`, and the file size is abnormal, too.

P.S.: it writes to the log file any time when there is request call for my api.

So, what's the reason cause the problem and how to solve it, has anyone met the
problem, hope for your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your python process hasn't been interrupted. Originally `TimedRotatingFileHandler` was designed for longtime running processes. If your process was restarted many times during the day you would notice misbehaviours.

The explanation can be found at [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/595931-timedrotatingfilehandler-isnt-rotating-midnight).

Please keep in mind the fact that Django's `runserver` by default restarts python process if  project files were updated.

Comment: The deployment I use is nginx + uwsgi + django. I import the logging.handler.TimeRotatingFileHandler in one of my applications' views.When there is a request call for the api,the app will record the request info into the log file. But sometimes the rotated yesterday file is not right, the file size is so small and the modified time is different from the right ones. Is this a bug of TimeRotatingFileHandler, or what causes the problem and how solve it? Despire for your help.